# Android GraphView 3.1 Shifting Vertical Origo Up/Down

Tags: java, android, scaling, android-graphview

I am developing an Android app that plots the gyroscope sensor input in a graph with the **GraphView 3.1**  library.

The data that I am feeding the GraphView is values between **-90 and 90**.

Due to that I want the graph to show both positive and negative values, I consequently want origo to be in the middle of the graph (vertically).

**Demo of the graph:**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtQOVU0GEEY

As you can see in the video, the graph starts with the x- and y-axis values in the top/bottom, **this is unwanted**, as it the values are 0 in both cases. They should both be in the middle (vertical center i.e. origo) when the x- and y-axis are 0. The graph should never shift the curve depending on subsequent values either, which is shown as soon as I tilt the device.

Do any of you have an idea of how to fix this?
I would like the plot consistent and not relative to the subsequent values.

The code that I am using is almost identical to the one jjoe64 has created in his demo:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphviewdemos/RealtimeGraph.java

Thanks!
Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix the y bounds with the method

```
graphview.setManualYAxisBounds(-100d, 100d);
```

[http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView.html#setManualYAxisBounds(double, double)](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView.html#setManualYAxisBounds%28double,%20double%29)